# Update input type="file" and keep path for image

Tags: php, file-upload

This is my code

```
<?php
include "../../../config/config.php";
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $id = $_GET['id'];
} else {
  die("Not found");
}

if (isset($_POST['submit-edit'])) {

  $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['title']);
  $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['description']);
  $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['category']);



  /* ----------------------- MAIN IMAGE  -------------------------- */
  $target_dir = "../../../img/find/thumbs-categorii/";
  $target_file2 = "" . basename($_FILES["img-edit"]["name"]);
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img-edit"]["name"]);

  $uploadOk = 1;
  $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  // Check file size
  if ($_FILES["img-edit"]["size"] > 100000) {
    $_SESSION['image-size'] = 1;
    exit();
  }
//    
  //Allow certain file formats
  if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
      && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != NULL) {
    $_SESSION['image-format'] = 1;

    exit();
  }

  // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
  if ($uploadOk == 0) {

    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
  } else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img-edit"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {



    } else {
      echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
//            exit();
    }


    $query = "UPDATE descopera_second" .
             "SET title='" . $title . "', text='" . $description . "', image='" .
             $target_file2 . "', fk_descopera_first='" . $category .
             "' WHERE id=" . $id;

    var_dump($query);
    exit();
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
//                var_dump($query);
//                exit();
    if ($result) {

      $_SESSION['edit_slider'] = 1;
      header("Location: /dashboard/");
    } else {
//          

      header("Location: /dashboard/");
    }
  }
}
?>
```

I want to keep the current path in database if the input with the image is empty. I don't know why, but my code currently stops at `echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";` and changes the path for the image, in my database. If the input is empty I want to keep the current path, because I just want to edit.

Comment: do you use  enctype="multipart/form-data" in <form> tag?

Comment: Yup... that's not the problem.

Comment: I saw the if is not going to else..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `$uploadOk = 1`, but that value never changes. So the following code, will **always** execute the `else` part of your condition.

```
if ($uploadOk == 0) {

} else {

    /* Everything in here will be executed */

}
```

Now look at all of the code that inside of that one conditional block.

The first thing is another condition.

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img-edit"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {

} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    // exit();
}
```

Where you say your code is stopping means that `move_uploaded_file` failed. This would be expected if the user did not supply a file upload in the request. Because `$target_file` will be empty, and an empty string is probably not going to be a valid path on your filesystem, plus there's the fact that **there was no file upload** in the first place even if it were.

Everything else that happens inside that first conditional block then continues to happen anyway, unconditionally (i.e. *updating your database even though there was no file uploaded*).

```
$query = "UPDATE descopera_second" .
         "SET title='" . $title . "', text='" . $description . "', image='" .
         $target_file2 . "', fk_descopera_first='" . $category .
         "' WHERE id=" . $id;
```

Try using [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var-dump) to inspect the value of `$target_file2` when this happens. It won't be what you expected. We know this because you initialize it as `$target_file2 = "" . basename($_FILES["img-edit"]["name"]);` above, and there was no file upload. So `$_FILES` is empty.

```
var_dump($target_file2);
```

So the better way to do this is to check if a valid file upload occurs first before attempting to update this value in your database. You *probably* meant to do this with your `$uploadOk` variable at the top.

```
if (isset($_FILES["img-edit"]["tmp_name"])) {
    $query = "UPDATE descopera_second" .
             "SET title='" . $title . "', text='" . $description . "', image='" .
             $target_file2 . "', fk_descopera_first='" . $category .
             "' WHERE id=" . $id;
} else {
    $query = "UPDATE descopera_second" .
             "SET title='" . $title . "', text='" . $description . "'," .
             ", fk_descopera_first='" . $category .
             "' WHERE id=" . $id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a little problem, i've tried to make the if(isset($_FILES['img-edit']['tmp_name'])) with two query. If the input is not empty  works, if the input is empty the query return me NULL.

Comment: Be sure to check [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/mysqli.error) for errors.

Comment: My bad, but the solution is the best! Thank you!:)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img-edit"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {
```

Comment: Maybe you could add a few explanation?